# Progressbar выводит только background изображение

Tags: android, progress-bar

Подскажите в чем ошибка при стилизации progressBarStyleHorizontal? Подменил у ProgressBar свойство progressDrawable, но выставление значений для контрола к видимым изменениям не приводит. Показывается только пустой ProgressBar.

Вот часть хмл из layout-а:

```
                <ProgressBar
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_custom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/progress_left"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progress_right"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/progressFull"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

вот кастомный drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_bg" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar"/>
</layer-list>
```

изображения - nine-patch png:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в коде значения:

```
    mFullProgress.setMax(100);
    mFullProgress.setProgress(70);
```

стиль приложения:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

скриншот пустого прогрессбара:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update** (результат правок):

В приницпе похоже на правду (см [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487416/17609)), но результат странный, вот скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update** (добавлен clip элемент в drawable):
После добавления clip для progress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_bg" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

контрол реагирует на изменение значений (progress и max):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update** (рабочее решение):
Проблема была в отсутсвии у nine-patch background изображения отметок об области контента. При рендеринге layer-list все слои после первого сжимались в 0 (при некоторых размерах контрола можно было видеть тонкую полоску).
поправленный бекграунд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_bg" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

верстка

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_custom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/progress_left"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progress_right"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/progressFull"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо правок моего ответа лучше дополняйте вопрос)

Comment: И попробуйте убрать аттрибуты высоты из стиля для прогресса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет, удаление этих атрибутов просто приводит к тому, что действуют атрибуты высоты от стиля-предка.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут в самом конце статьи](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar.php). Возможно поможет использование стандартной темы, но назначение `drawable` программно.

Comment: Либо поробуйте заменить nine-patch на что-то другое. Может в них проблема ещё.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ага для беграунд части убрал nine-patch, странный padding убрался.

Comment: Значит вам теперь надо мой ответ назначить "верным" и задавать новый вопрос по поводу правильного создания nine-patch)

Comment: да, спасибо за помощь )

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, еще раз спасибо )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, возможно, в конфликте стиля виджета и присвоенного `drawable`.

Попробуйте определить собственную тему для него как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893453/3212712):

В стилях: `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources> 
    <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progressbar_custom</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Тут всё остальное из стилей. В смысле не в комменте а просто дальше в файле)-->
</resources>
```

И назначаем наш кастомный стиль:

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar" />
```